# Finding values in row and column

Tags: matlab

I am given a 5x2 file. First column is time and second is measurements.
first column `'10, 10.5, 10.75, 11, 11.25` second column `2,4,8, 10, 12`
The user will input a measurement and the machine will say what time it occured. Example I want to know what time 8 was measured, the answer should be 10.75.

Answer (score 0):

Use the find command to search for the measurement value in your second column. Use that index to retrieve time from your first column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've read the file into `dat`:

```
dat = [
    10,   2;
    10.5,  4;
    10.75, 8;
    11,    10
    11.25, 12];
```

Something like this would work:

```
x = input('Enter measurement: ');

match = a(:,2)==x;

t = a(match,1);

disp(t)
```

It doesn't cover what happens if there is no match or more than one match. That can be an exercise for the reader.